# Given the following clues, is this number irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Given $ a, b \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ c \in   \mathbb{Q}_{+}$, if $ a^c $ and $ b^c $ are irrational, with $ a $ and $ b $ coprime, is $ \frac{a^c}{b^c} $ irrational too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting Anas Ibrahim's answer:

We have (from Anas) $c=m/n$ in its lowest terms (so $m$ and $n$ have no common prime factor). Also
\begin{align*}
qa^c&=pb^c\\
\implies q^n a^m &= p^n b^m
\end{align*}
$a$ and $b$ have no common prime factor. Nor do $p$ and $q$. So, by unique factorization, the only way the LHS and RHS can be the same integer is if $a^m=p^n$ and $b^m=q^n$. But $m$ and $n$ have no common prime factor either. So the only way that $a^m$ and $b^m$ can both be $n$th powers is if $a$ and $b$ are themselves $n$th powers. But in that case $a^c$ and $b^c$ are rational, which contradicts the premiss of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this a bit more clearer, now I understand the proof. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because suppose for the sake of contradiction that$$\frac{a^c}{b^c}=\frac{p}{q} \iff qa^c=pb^c$$
Now let $c=\frac{m}{n}$ for coprime $m$ and $n$, we have
$$q\sqrt[n]{a^m}=p\sqrt[n]{b^m}$$
But since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then the right handside and the left handside are two different irrational numbers, meaning $q\sqrt[n]{a^m} \ne p\sqrt[n]{b^m}$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand the last part. How is it possible that just because a and b are coprime, then the equality doesn't hold?

Comment: I mean, take for example $\sqrt[3]{24}$ and $\sqrt[3]{625}$ (I mean, instead of $\sqrt[n]{a^m}$ and $\sqrt[n]{b^m}$), one of them equals $2\sqrt[3]{3}$ while the other is $5\sqrt[3]{5}$, and being coprime means that the both leave coprime numbers under the root.

Comment: To make it more rigorous, if $m>n$, and so $m=kn+d$ for some positive integer $k$ and $0<d<n$, then our equation turns out
$$qa^k \sqrt[n]{a^d}=pb^k \sqrt[n]{b^d}$$
Leaving yet again two different irrational numbers

Comment: So this is true only if $m>n$?

Comment: No, if $m<n$ it would also be true, but you'd not need to make the separation I just made and take out the $a^k$ or $b^k$

Comment: What I mean is, when you simplify $\sqrt[n]{a^m}$ and $\sqrt[n]{b^m}$ after giving the prime factorization of $a$ and $b$, they both leave different primes/irreducible roots under their root because they are coprime, and hence the two are different irrational numbers and they cannot be equal.

Comment: Here you only talked about extracting from the rope, but if q and p for your proof are two integer such that the equality holds?

Comment: Sorry, I meant *root*, not *rope*

Comment: It can't be. The integers multiplied by a root doesn't affect whether one root equals the other.
For example
$p\sqrt{2} \ne q\sqrt{3}$, no matter what. Because $2p^2 \ne 3q^2$ whatever integers $p$ and $q$ you apply.

Comment: Notice that there are groups of numbers like $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ where all numbers are in the form of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.
However, $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.
and that applies to other numbers as well.